# i am not able to show new user address in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am working on React/Redux e-commerce project, I am making functionality of adding user address, the functionality is working fine, I am able to add new user address, but the problem is I have to refresh the page to show the new address card, Address card is not showing after saving the address, I have to refresh the page to show the new address, can anyone help to solve this issue, my actions, reducers and saga file is attached below

**Action file**

```
const addAddressByBuyerId = (address: Object, params: string) => ({
    type: Types.ADD_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID,
    address,
    params,
});
const addAddressByBuyerIdSuccess = (addresses: Object, params: string) => ({
    type: Types.ADD_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_SUCCESS,
    addresses,
    params,
});
const addAddressByBuyerIdFailure = (errorMessage: Object) => ({
    type: Types.ADD_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_FAILURE,
    errorMessage,
});
```

**saga file**

```
function* addAddressByBuyerId(action) {
        try {
            const response = yield call(api.account.postAddressByBuyerId, action.address);
            if (response.ok && response.data && {}.hasOwnProperty.call(response.data, 'data')) {
                yield put(Actions.getAddressesByBuyerId());
                yield put(Actions.addAddressByBuyerIdSuccess(response.data.data));
            } else {
                yield put(Actions.addAddressByBuyerIdFailure(response.errorMessage));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            yield put(Actions.addAddressByBuyerIdFailure());
        }
    }
    function* watchAddAddressByBuyerId(): Generator<void, void, void> {
        yield takeLatest(Types.ADD_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID, addAddressByBuyerId);
    }
```

**Reducers file**

```
export const addAddressByBuyerId = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    successMessage: null,
    errorMessage: null,
});

export const addAddressByBuyerIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => {
    const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-added', {}, 'Address added!');
    return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        isLoading: false,
        successMessage,
    };
};

export const addAddressByBuyerIdFailure = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
    ...state,
    errorMessage: action.errorMessage || genericError,
    isLoading: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

In action file you return an object that contains `addresses` property (see `addAddressByBuyerIdSuccess` function).

However in your reducer (`addAddressByBuyerIdSuccess`) you are accessing `address` property which is undefined.